# Log-Log regression and cost function

Tags: regression, forecasting, loss-functions, model-evaluation, logarithm

I have made a very simple linear regression model having used log-log transformation for the y and one of the independent variables:
$log(y)=B_0+log(X_1)B_1+X_2B_2$ where $B_0$ is the intercept and $B_1,B_2$ the coefficients.

**My question is** : if I want to evaluate the model and its predictions using cost function $J=\frac{1}{2m}\times \sum(\hat{y}-y)^2$, should I first revert $\hat{y}$(prediction) and $y$(actual) by taking their exponentials?

Also considering that I am doing this exercise in Excel and not using gradient descent to optimize my parameters, how do I evaluate $J$ without other lines to compare? i.e. $J=160$ by itself has any value for evaluating the model?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you please post a link to the raw data before transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should, but also you should consider other alternatives. Least squares regression minimizes squares of residuals of the variable you use for regression, so if you use transformed y, it will minimize squared residuals over trasformed space, and that is not what your cost function is like, maybe some kind of nonlinear least squares regression could be better for your case.

If you want to stick with your linear model, you may want to transform back your variable this way: $\hat y = exp(\hat{ln(y)} + \frac{s^2}{2})$. This will minimize your cost function if your model has normal residuals (transforming back y will make its distribution skewed, so its expected value will shift, the formula comes from [here](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuzione_lognormale)).

Comment: I need to stick with linead model as the exercise's goal is to address non linearity with log or semilog tranformation before running a regression. Noted with thanks your comments - how about interpreting the cost function result for evaluating the effe tiveness of the model without more equations to compare the J with?

Comment: I don't know where that J comes from, maybe it has some reference value, considering its meaning and your data, but in general, for a given model, loss function value doesn't have any intrinsic meaning and can be always used only as a comparison with other models performances.

Comment: That makes sense I guess thanks

Comment: would you mark the answer as accepted?